# Why am I seeing (erroneous?) flags notifications in the site's top bar?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Occasionally when I log in, I see a notification count (with a yellow background) to the left of the "tools" link:

[image]

This is *not* the suggested edit count notification, which is orange and usually shows up to the right of the "tools" link (if I recall correctly). When I hover over this notification badge, I get a tooltip telling me there are flags to be acted on.

However, clicking the icon brings me to the last "tools" page I was at, and there are never any flagged posts displayed. Previously I have only see flagged post count notifications when I was already navigated to the tools page, and never in the top bar. Anybody know what's going on? Is this a bug?

Comment: Perhaps this is unrelated, but I also just noticed that I can't actually scroll to the bottom of the flags page in the tools view (using Safari 5.1.1 (7534.51.22) on a Mac). As soon as the footer with the copyright and SE link collection would scroll into view, the page jumps back up to the top of the page. Weird.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. Basically, for obvious reasons when you go to that page we filter out any flags *about you*. No: those 7 weren't for you! However, there was a bug (to do with database nulls) which meant that this filter was *also* excluding posts by deleted users.

However, the *count* in the page-header is much simpler and doesn't apply this check - hence it was reporting the flags for deleted users, when the main screen was not.

(I should clarify; this does *not* mean that flags against deleted users were not being processed - it just means that only ♦ moderators could see them).

This bug is fixed in the next build, and I've also rigged it to report the number of *posts* rather than the number of *flags*.